# Ubuntu taking long to shutdown

Tags: unity, shutdown, 15.04, plymouth, dmesg

[image: Plymouth boot screen error]

I use Ubuntu 15.04, I have a SSD drive also. Very recently onwards the ubuntu is taking long to shut down nearly 1:30 minutes.

I checked the shutdown log messages and I get the follow message.

```
A stop job is running for Session c2 of user ***** (25s/ 1min 30 s)
```

It count downs till 1:30 minutes and then shutdown the machine.

Why is it happening.

Comment: see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/626144/crazy-boot-and-reboot-times-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-15-04

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: I found the particular process that was taking long to shut down and would go to system monitor and kill it manually. Then if you shut-down it will. But I didn't find a permanent solution for it yet.