# Crazy boot and reboot times after upgrading to ubuntu 15.04 (a stop/start job is running for session c2)

Tags: boot, 15.04, reboot

After upgrade to 15.04 my ubuntu loads really slowly, slower than Windows 8 on the same machine, which insults me.

I turned off splash screen, and when I boot the system I get this:

```
A start job is running for dev-hdb2.device
```

and It stays that way for 1:30 minute, with a time counter next to it set exactly to 1:30.

Also when I reboot I get this message:

```
A stop job is running for Session c2 of user MrMino
```

same here - it stays that way for 1:30

Output of dmesg:
http://pastebin.com/yzbFQG05

Unfortunately bootchart isn't working for some reason not known to me now, so I can't post logs from it.

How to make this go away?
I'm running ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 3537.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/615006 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/626115/ for just two examples of how using the diagnostic tools that come with systemd give far more information in a question.

Comment: There's a related bug-report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1457400 .

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by rolling back from systemd to upstart. More info here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

```
Permanent switch back to upstart
Install the upstart-sysv package, which will remove ubuntu-standard 
and systemd-sysv (but should not remove anything else -- if it does, yell!), 
and run sudo update-initramfs -u. After that, grub's "Advanced options" 
menu will have a corresponding "Ubuntu, with Linux ... (systemd)" 
entry where you can do an one-time boot with systemd.

If you want to switch back to systemd, install the systemd-sysv and ubuntu-standard packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my Manjaro, searching I found a post in a reddit forum of Arch Linux.

Here is the solution that works for me
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4bawf7/a_stop_job_is_running_for_session_c2_of_user/d17th3u

You need to ubuntulize it:

> Install watchdog
>
> `# pacman -S watchdog`
>
> And then start the service at boot:
>
> `#  systemctl enable watchdog.service`
>
> Start the service to don't see the message any more
>
> `# systemctl start watchdog.service`

I create a gist for this https://gist.github.com/dianjuar/98d02af4050dc2df8ae6f18695d44ca3

Comment: Hey, it's nice that someone finally answered this. I would love to check if it works, but I'm now running Ubuntu Gnome, and it has no problem with this.  +1 For the gist though.